# DateTime.Compare(start, end) resulting weired in my system

Tags: c#

[image]

In the above picture you can see that the `start` and `end` value is same. but the compare method is returning -1, which means start time is less than end time. How is this possible?

I have tried sample values in a console application to test comapre method, & its working fine. I think here may be some internal value of `datetime` object is not matching. But couldn't find.

**Here is the code.**

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(pi.StartTime), end = Convert.ToDateTime(pi.EndTime);

int t1 = DateTime.Compare(start, end);

if (t1 == 0)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Start Time and End Time are same.");
     return;
}
else if (t1 == 1)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Start Time is greater then end time.");
     return;
}
```

Comment: Milliseconds  components are not shown with this date format.

Comment: Use the debugger and check their `Ticks` properties. I'm pretty sure they don't match.

Comment: @Ksv3n is right. Just after the posting of Question, I checked each properties and found that there are difference of 127 miliseconds. WOW!
And then I convert my system datetime to string and then again converting to datetime (as the milisecond become 0). so everything works fine now. So is it ok what I am doing?

Comment: I think that you should try to fix the source of the problem - why are you getting the different time inputs, when they should be the same.

Comment: @SonerGönül Check my last comment and as it is solved, I think, I should keep the question and put an answer how I solved. If any one faces same kind of problem, then it may help. What do you think?  And my Tick is OK.

Comment: Also, it is not advised to use time>string>time method as it will make problem less frequent and obvious.

Comment: @Dusan this milisecond difference should occur, I think. Cause they are coming from two different datetimepicker in WPF. and they are loading data in from datetime.now while form loading. so there should be a time diff.

Comment: @Dusan yep. you are right. its also od to me to converting like that. 
Dmitry Bychenko have posted an answer, and its working fine. I think I should folow the answer.

Comment: @AbdurRahim: Read my answer regarding if your solution is fine or not.

Comment: @AbdurRahim You wrote `And then I convert my system datetime to string and then again converting to datetime (as the milisecond become 0). so everything works fine now` That sounds awfull, have you tried `DateTime.Compare(start.AddMilliseconds(-start.Millisecond), end.AddMilliseconds(-end.Millisecond));` You could also create an extension method for that and use `DateTime.Compare(start.TrimMilliseconds(), stop.TrimMilliseconds())` https://gist.github.com/Steinblock/7407f7d2218fc46a7e0d

Comment: @SchlaWiener You should put it as an answer. Though I have accepted an answer , but in future, it may be helpful for others.

Comment: Using trimming is a best general solution as shown in Dmitry's answer - you need to truncate time to precision your users actually can input and see in the GUI.
For example, if user is able to input/see `hh:mm` then you should always truncate time up to a minute (ignore seconds, milliseconds...).
This will remove any ambiguity for both users and in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest comparison with *tolerance*, e.g. trimming off *milliseconds*:

```
int t1 = DateTime.Compare(
  new DateTime(start.Ticks - (start.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond), start.Kind),
  new DateTime(end.Ticks - (end.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond), end.Kind));
```

Answer (score 2):

> Just after the posting of Question, I checked each properties and found that there are difference of 127 miliseconds. WOW! And then I convert my system datetime to string and then again converting to datetime (as the milisecond become 0). so everything works fine now. So is it ok what I am doing?

No. By doing a conversion you do not communicate intent. The one reading your code will not understand why you did like that.

A much better way would be:

```
var difference = date1.Substract(date2).TotalSeconds;
return Math.Abs(difference) < 1;
```

Because then you show in the code that you accept a small difference (and how large difference you allow).

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Compares two instances of DateTime and returns an integer that
>   indicates whether the first instance is earlier than, the same as, or
>   later than the second instance.

Then it says :

> To determine the relationship of t1 to t2, the Compare method compares
>   the Ticks property of t1 and t2 but ignores their Kind property.
>   Before comparing DateTime objects, ensure that the objects represent
>   times in the same time zone.

And that s why you're having that result : here's an example :

**Edit :**

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);

        date2 = date2.AddMilliseconds(2);

        int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
        string relationship;

        if (result < 0)
            relationship = "is earlier than";
        else if (result == 0)
            relationship = "is the same time as";
        else
            relationship = "is later than";

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//    8/1/2009 12:00:00 AM is earlier than 8/1/2009 12:00:00 AM
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: no,this is not my case. & before posting I have checked MSDN, It would be better to share the link instead of copying them and submit as a answer.

Comment: 12 AM will always be earlier than 12 PM for the same date. I don't understand how this answers the question.

Comment: @AbdurRahim You said : " I checked each properties and found that there are difference of 127 miliseconds." This is exactly your case, the Ticks Property is different

Comment: @AbdurRahim Sorry the example is misplaced, the Quotes aren't though

Comment: @AbdurRahim fixed the example, is it your case now ?

Comment: @AbdurRahim Concerning the link, I put it since the beginning in the very first line !! and it says "From MSDN" , and if you checked MSDN you' would have understood yout problem !!

Answer (score 1):

You can compare

```
DateTime.Compare(
    start.AddMilliseconds(-start.Millisecond), 
    end.AddMilliseconds(-end.Millisecond)
);
```

or even better with an extension method

```
DateTime.Compare(start.TrimMilliseconds(), stop.TrimMilliseconds())

public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime TrimMilliseconds(this DateTime date)
    {
        return date.AddMilliseconds(-date.Millisecond);
    }
}
```

please not that DateTime values are immutable so you are comparing two different DateTime values. start and end are not modified and are still differnt. you can avoid that with trimming the milliseconds during assignment

```
var start = DateTime.Now.TrimMilliseconds();
```